# Combining records from 2 tables into 1 ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, refactoring

I'm looking for some advice on how to handle the below problem. There may be a design pattern or rails way of handling this.

**Problem**

I currently have a table and model for legacy_posts. There are several different types of post stored in the legacy_posts table. It's not really scalable nor fit for purpose so I am migrating away from this setup.

I will be using a new table and model called posts. I have to migrate each post type one by one, without impacting the end user. *I don't have a choice in this, it must be done one post type at a time*. The end user shouldn't notice any difference while migrating.

Where I run into trouble is on the index page for my legacy_posts and posts table. Up until now, with only the legacy_notes table it has been trivial to display, paginate and sort my data with ActiveRecord. However, now I need to list both posts and legacy_posts on this page and I don't want to have custom logic to handle my pagination, sorting etc.

**Temp Solution**

I figure that if I do a UNION join of my posts and legacy_posts table, and then allow my legacy_post model to select from here I can still use ActiveRecord's sort, order, pagination etc.

```
In legacy_posts controller

def combined_posts
  posts = user.posts.select(
    :id,
    'title as heading'
    etc...
  )
  legacy_posts = user.legacy_posts.all
  combined_posts = user.legacy_posts.select('*').from("((#{legacy_posts.to_sql}) UNION (#{posts.to_sql})) AS legacy_posts")
  combined_posts.order('posted_at DESC').page(params[:page] || 0).per(params[:items])
end
```

This works fine for me but it feels very hacky. I'm wondering if there is a better way to approach this or if there is a pattern that could be used?

Comment: I don't think its really that hacky. You have an unusual situation where you need a union from two tables and I would probally do the same thing. What you can do to clean it up is use Arel to create the union instead of creating a SQL string with interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

I think creating a database view would be the cleanest solution. You can do so by creating a new migration and do something like this.

```rb
def up
  execute <<-SQL
    create view posts_view as
      select id, title as heading ... from legacy_posts
      union
      select id, heading from posts
  SQL
end

def down
  execute <<-SQL
    drop view posts_view
  SQL
end
```

Then create a model file with

```rb
class PostsView < ApplicationRecord
  # Not strictly necessary but I like to do this for views
  # if you want to update the name later
  self.table_name = "posts_view"

  # Model is readonly
  def readonly?
    true
  end
end
```

And use it like any other model

```rb
PostsView.where(user_id: 1).paginate.....
```

---

Reading:

- https://www.netguru.com/blog/database-views-and-how-to-use-them-in-a-ror-based-app
- https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic

Comment: This approach look fine, but what about situation, when one or both of source tables are updated?

Comment: What do you mean updated, the data or the schema?